# Python Openpyxl: cell value changed by function not executed in main

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` to validate a workbook and change some values depending on other values in other cells.

Right now, I have one piece of code that does like 90% of the validation and changes. My main file started getting pretty large and so I started writing a second file where I could put in new rules and execute further changes.

I am having no issues with the first code validating the workbook and making changes, but the second file won't make any changes when I call it from within the first. I made some example scripts and I am still hitting the same issue.

For reference, the array from the excel workbook is as follows: (workbook is also attached)

Reported "HighestNumber" (cell A2) = 11

"CheckCell"s (cells B2:K2) = 6, 22, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0

The second script should see that value in A2 (11) is less than one of the values in B2:K2 (22) and change A2 to 22.

Right now, in the second code, it realizes that 11 is less than 22 but isn't actually writing the change when the function finishes. (readout from print at the bottom)

I am probably missing something super obvious, as I am still very new to a lot of this and don't have any formal education in it so I know the mistake is probably silly.

This is the main Test1.py

```
import sys
import os
import openpyxl as oxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.descriptors.excel import Coordinate
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from Test2 import Validate

filename = sys.argv[1]
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1])

wb = oxl.load_workbook(filename, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
rows = iter(ws.rows)

# Create Header Dictionary
headers = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]

ColNames = {}
Current  = 0
for COL in ws.iter_cols(0, ws.max_column):
    ColNames[COL[0].value] = Current
    Current += 1 

for idx, row in enumerate(rows):
    # skip the first indexed row (0) Header Row.
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    if all(cell.value is None for cell in row):
        break
    for cell in row:
        header = headers[cell.column-1]
        colNum = ColNames.get(header)

        # some stuff is done here......
    # after doing stuff        
    x = idx+1
    print('before from main value is ' + str(ws.cell(row=idx+1,column=ColNames.get('HighestNumber')+1).value))
    Validate(x)
    print('after from main value is ' + str(ws.cell(row=idx+1,column=ColNames.get('HighestNumber')+1).value))

# saving the destination excel file 
# Make sure workbook isnt open
try:
    wb.save(str(filename)) 
    os.startfile(pathname + '\\' + filename)

except OSError:
    messagebox.showinfo('Notice','Workbook is open by current user or another user. Close the workbook then try again')
```

and this is the second one Test2.py

```
import sys
import os
import openpyxl as oxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = sys.argv[1]
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1])
wb = oxl.load_workbook(filename, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
rows = iter(ws.rows)

# Create Header Dictionary
headers = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]

ColNames = {}
Current  = 0
for COL in ws.iter_cols(0, ws.max_column):
    ColNames[COL[0].value] = Current
    Current += 1 

# Named Range
CheckRange = ['CheckCell1','CheckCell2','CheckCell3','CheckCell4','CheckCell5','CheckCell6','CheckCell7','CheckCell8','CheckCell9','CheckCell10']

def Validate(x):
    print('Test2 begin run')
    RuleViolations = []
    ChangedValues = []

    for cell in ws[x]:
        # print(cell.coordinate)
        header = headers[cell.column-1]
        if header == 'HighestNumber':
            AllValues = []
            ReportedHighest = ws.cell(row=x,column=ColNames.get('HighestNumber')+1)
            for header in CheckRange:
                p = ws.cell(row=x,column=ColNames.get(header)+1)
                AllValues.append(p.value)
            ActualHighest = max(AllValues)
            if ActualHighest > ReportedHighest.value:
                print('value before from def ' +str(ReportedHighest.value))
                ReportedHighest.value = ActualHighest
                print('value after from def ' +str(ReportedHighest.value))

    print('Test2 end run')
```

when I run the main, this is what I get back:

```
before from main value is 11
Test2 begin run
value before from def 11
value after from def 22
Test2 end run
after from main value is 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with scope, which you can read about here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Essentially, when you're passing X into your validate function, the function is then working with it's own little copy of X, and isn't able to alter the original from outside of the function. Your main script is then only seeing the original because the validate function isn't making any change.

What you should do is have your Validate function return X after making it's changes, and then in your main script set X to the result of that validation. IE:

```
def validate(x):
   ..stuff..
   return x
```

and then in your main script:

```
x = validate(x) // setting the value to the updated, validated version
```